Angular SSR - route identifier with dot
I have the following routerlink
<a [routerLink]="item['key']">{{item['name']}}</a>

This is my route:
{path: 'protocol/analysis/:id', component: ProAnalysisComponent},

When the user clicks on the link, he is directed to:
http://localhost:4200/protocol/analysis/filename.pdf

However, after updating my angular app to Angular 18 with SSR, that link stopped working because of the dot in the route identifier. I get the error message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

If I edit the URL to the following it works:
http://localhost:4200/protocol/analysis/"filename.pdf"

How do I fix this issue with the route identifier containing a dot?

Solution 1. If you're using SSR, the issue might also be on the server side.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

Solution 2. I am going to assume the pdf file is static which makes it easier, using this code
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/your-app-name')));

// Wildcard route to handle all other requests
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/your-app-name/index.html'));
});

Solution 3. Let's see if the dot is misinterpreted by the server, I have provided the code below:
<a [routerLink]="['/protocol/analysis', item['key'].replace(/\./g, '%2E')]">{{item['name']}}</a>


am afraid encoding the filename is not resolving the issue. I am using SSR

strange, have you tried using express.static? making the file static? would you like to modify the server-side routing?

the filename is used as an id and the page is just another html page. My only issue is that the filename has a dot for the extension and as a result it is failing when calling the url with the filename

@Kim I have updated the code let's see if the server behaves, try the last one

Thanks Derek. I basically added '%22' before and after the id and decoded it on the receiving end using decodeURIComponent. I'll try your solution as well

You can encode and send it using encodeURIComponent.
getEncoded(path: string) {
  return encodeURIComponent(path);
}

HTML will be.
<a [routerLink]="getEncoded(item['key'])">{{item['name']}}</a>

Then in the receiving place decode it using decodeURIComponent
